# Dimension of $MS$ where $M\in M_{m\times n}$ and $S\le \mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra

Could anyone tell me how  to find the formulae for  $\dim MS$ where $M\in M_{m\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ and 
$S\le \mathbb{R}^n$ be  a subspace and $MS=\{Mx:x\in S\}$

I thought $M:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^m$ a linear map. suppose it has some kernel $K$ of dimension say $r<n$ and say $\dim S=p$, may be $S\cap K\ne \phi$ or $K\cap S=\phi$, also I know the famous $\dim ker(M)+\dim (im(M))=n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply the rank-nullity theorem to the restriction of (the linear map defined by) $M$ to the subspace $S$, giving
$$
  \dim(MS)=\dim(S)-\dim(S\cap K),
$$
since the kernel of that restriction is precisely $S\cap K$.